# Connected service WCF not work NET core 3.1

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, soap

I have to call a soap service and I want to do it through a connected service in .net core 3.1,

First I configure the url of the WSDL and then I select the service I want to use but when creating it it generates a framework version error

Here the steps follow:

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: error step 3]

Is there a solution? considering I should use net core 3.1?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the failure to add a service reference is probably that the binding or nuget package of the wcf needed is not supported in .netcore. You can refer to this link to see if it is supported in .netcore: [WCF Features in .Net Core](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v2.0.0.md). And in .netcore, the alternative to wcf service is [gRPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).